# PHP to MS SQL Server adapter

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework2

I'm currently developing a app on PHP(5.3) with Zend Framework (2).
The customer **recently** announced that that the target database will be MS SQL Server.

So .. I checked several DB adapter options:

**PDO_MSSQL** seems to be deprecated.

**SQLSRV**  works only for windows servers ?

**PDO_ODBC** seems as the right choice for different OS support.

Any suggestion what is the proper way to do it in with Zend will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQLSRV works only for windows servers ?

Sure, the library PHP wraps is only available for windows.

> PDO_MSSQL seems to be deprecated.

You means **PDO_SQLSRV**. Where you get this information from? You find required information within [PDO_SQLSRV](http://php.net/manual/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)

> PDO_ODBC seems as the right choice for different OS support.

Yes, see [PDO_ODBC](http://php.net/manual/ref.pdo-odbc.php) and [ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160)

> Any suggestion what is the proper way to do it in with Zend will be appreciated.

ZF2 will support this using both drivers since 2.1 (alpha/ or beta ~ next week)
Read [this](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2-documentation/blob/master/docs/languages/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.rst)

Comment: with "PDO_MSSQL" I ment "php mssql extention" http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php

Comment: The mssql extension is no longer available (since PHP 5.3) and has nothing todo with PDO.

Answer (score 2):

I used have once used http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php and coded my own Zend Wrapper around that. Not the easiest way but I wanted control of all the small differences between MSSQL and MySQL.

But doesn't the following settings work?

```
resources.db.adapter                             = "sqlsrv"
resources.db.host                                = "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"
resources.db.dbname                              = "DatabaseName"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter               = true 
resources.db.driver_options.ReturnDatesAsStrings = true
```

Saw something like this proposed some time ago.

And btw, is this Zend Framework 1 or 2 we are talking about?

Comment: It is ZF2, I got problems when I tried  adding "php_sqlsrv" to my dev environment... and when check more deep in to it, it seems to be only for Win OS .. and I will probably need more flexible variant.

Answer (score 1):

use freetds with pdo dblib. there i have a blog post written how to use it (in ZF1):
http://featurebug.blogspot.de/2011/04/linux-php-and-zend-framework-and-ms-sql.html

P.S. there is no sqlsrv for linux/Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

Brute force tactic ..
SQLSRV was not loaded .. because it is external driver and there are over 15 possible builds 
depending on php version, VS version, SQL server driver ..

So .. I downloaded them all and tried each of them one by one

with a php test page like this:

```
echo "is 'sqlsrv' loaded: " . (extension_loaded('sqlsrv')?'yes':'no') ;
```

The last one before the last worked  :)

The property for zend was `resources.db.adapter = "sqlsrv"`

I also was promptet to "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client"

But .. no idea how to install it on Linux/Mac